# Testing convergence of the series of $n^p((n-1)^{-1/2}-n^{-1/2})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

Exercise 8.15 (l) of *Analysis* by Apostol states:

Test for convergence: $$\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty n^p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)$$

The solution I have states as the first step: "Note that
$$ n^p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) = \frac{1}{n^{3/2-p}}\left( \sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}}  \right)"$$

This step is not very self evident for me, could some one help me understand how we would obtain this equality.

Comment: Hint:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n - 1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n - 1}}{\sqrt{n(n - 1)}} = \frac{n - (n - 1)}{(\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n - 1})\sqrt{n(n - 1)}}$$

Comment: Take a look here <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916107/convergence-of-sum-n-2-infty-np-left-frac1-sqrtn-1-frac1-sqrt-n>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start with (ignoring the $n^p$ for the time being)

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n-1}\sqrt{n}},$$

then you rationalise the numerator, using $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} = \frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$, getting

$$\frac{n-(n-1)}{\sqrt{n-1}\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1})}.$$

Now the numerator is $1$, and when you extract $(\sqrt{n})^3$ from the denominator, you get

$$\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}\left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}\right)},$$

from which the given form is easily obtainable.